# Kendo Grid: Trigger Update click on enter key press for popup editing

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using the Kendo UI Grid with popup editing. By default, when the user is editing a field in the popup editor and hits the enter key the data is rendered to the grid (behind the popup editor) but the popup stays visible and the save event is not fired until you click the 'Update' button.

I'm trying to change that functionality so that when a user hits enter while editing a field it would trigger the 'Update' button click - meaning it would render the data to the grid, fire the save event and close the popup editor.

My current attempt will just close the popup editor but does not fire the save event and undoes the changes made to any fields for the selected row. Almost like the cancel button was triggered instead.

```
options.edit = function (e) {
    $('.k-edit-field .k-input').on('keypress', function (e) {
        utils.onEnter(e, function () {
            $('.k-grid-update').trigger('click');
        });
    });
};
```

**How can I trigger the 'Update' button click, or at least simulate what it does?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a kendo method to cause the changed fields to become dirty and then be saved, so I used a little jQuery and just shifted the focus to the update button then triggered the click event. Works as expected...

```
options.edit = function (e) {
    $('.k-edit-field .k-input').on('keypress', function (e) {
        utils.onEnter(e, function () {
            $('.k-grid-update').focus().trigger('click');

        });
    });
};
```

Comment: This worked for me too, but in 1 second I've got a js error: 
Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'getSelection' in undefined.

Stacktrace won't say anything useful, something internal.
If I click on update btn by mouse - everything is ok..

Comment: @bflemi3 Thanks for your question and answer but what is options? where did you write this function? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @MustafaP I believe he's hooking into the [edit event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit) via [setOptions](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setOptions).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the [saveRow method](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#saverow) which will save the current data and close the PopUp editor.

e.g.:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").saveRow();
```

Comment: Maybe this works for inline editing but it doesn't work for popup editing.

Comment: Problem is, the input field first has to lose focus before the model will be updated.